# how to place text on button at edges in android

Tags: android, button

[image: Button with text on extreme edges]

I want to place text in a button on the extreme edges that is 
**Click** on the left part of the button and **Here** on the right part of the button. How this can be achieved.

i have used the TAG`android:text="Click Here"`, as the button is on the full screen i want these words to be at extreme edges

Comment: You can use a `linearLayout` with `horizontal` orientation. And place two `textView` on both ends.

Comment: @AnshulTyagi how to include text using another layout

Comment: @AnshulTyagi is there any solution for this thing

Comment: You can make `clickable` to textViews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below `RelativeLayout`. You can customize the values. Here you can make all of the `RelativeLayout` and `TextView`s act like a button by setting them `OnClickListener`s.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mybutton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:background="#3983B1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leftButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Click"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rightButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Here"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The layout looks like:

[image]

Comment: thanks man it is working fine, but how to set the error message on this view using setError("Error");

Comment: solved by setting errorMessage on the other part of the current layout